# Will chkdsk and sfc /scannow fix a corrupted winload.efi file?

Tags: windows, chkdsk, microsoft-surface, recovery

Super User, I found an iso for my Surface finally... Can I run chkdsk and sfc /scannow to fix a corrupted winload.efi file? I can't reset my Surface because it has a lot of work on it and it is stuck in Recovery. (0xc000000f) I've read running chkdsk and sfc will fix bad sectors and fix corrupted boot files.

Comment: SFC should fix any corrupted system files.

Comment: Alright! I can get back to work!

Comment: I recommend you to back up your files regularly, as good practise, in case you aren't able to boot into it one day.

Comment: I get it could happen. This has happened multiple times. Not just one. This one just hit winload.efi, not my BCD.

Comment: However this work I went to do, was started the day that happened

Comment: Hey Moab if you put that as a answer i'll count it :)